# How can I use WebRTC to send a live webcam stream from the frontend to the backend?

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, reactjs, .net

I am currently building a basic Streamyard clone that captures the live webcam stream from the user's browser and needs to send it to the backend for further processing and conversion into the required format for streaming on platforms like YouTube. Similar to Streamyard, I want to seamlessly integrate this stream with other streaming platforms.

I have successfully implemented video stream capture from the webcam using the JavaScript getUserMedia() API. However, I am now faced with the challenge of sending this live video stream to the backend using WebRTC.

I understand that WebRTC is primarily used for peer-to-peer (P2P) communication, but in my case, there is no need for a P2P connection since I only have a client (frontend) and a server (backend). The frontend needs to continuously send the real-time video stream to the backend, which will handle processing and overlays.

Is it possible to leverage WebRTC to send the live video stream to the backend without establishing a P2P connection? If so, how can I achieve this? I want to use WebRTC because I need to apply overlays and other real-time modifications to the live video stream before it's sent to streaming platforms. Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible and Yes WebRTC is the right way to go.

It is still going to be a P2P connection, one peer is a web browser, another peer is your back-end server. In WebRTC you can setup things so one peer (browser) just does publishing of the video which you capture using getUserMedia(), and another peer (the back-end server) just receives that stream.

Ant Media Server, Unreal Media Server, Wowza Media Server - take a look at these. Here is live demo:
https://unrealstreaming.net:8443/UnrealWebRTCPublishingDemo/publish.aspx